# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in /tmp/... wordpress

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have jupiter theme installed and activated on my wordpress website. And it's working very fine till yesterday. But now the site is not opening and showing below error. Also same error comes when I tries to open admin panel (http://growthworldwide.in/wp-admin/)

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in /tmp/theme_temp_setupYD75Y9 on line 2.
```

every time it comes with some different string at last (after theme_temp_setup).
This is shared hosting with cPanel on it. When I goes to File Manager there are many folders like public_html, public_ftp, mail, .cagefs, .cpanel, .cphorde, .cl.selector, .pki, .htpasswds, .softaculous, .trash, logs, softaculous_backups, ssl, tmp, and many more.
[Screen shot showing folders under home](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPwxi.png)

When I goes into .cagefs folder there comes three folders opt, tmp, var. and this error is related to files listed under this tmp folder. There is one file named mysql.sock. When I deleted it then the site started showing different error that problem connecting with database or some other problems. So I think there is some service stopped or something else.

If you could please help me resolve this issue. Thank You.

Attached two log files which is generated under tmp folder.
growthwo_26_75141_upgrade_err.log

```
NOTICE Undefined offset: 1 /usr/local/cpanel/whostmgr/docroot/cgi/softaculous/enduser/main/functions.php 11536
NOTICE Undefined index: pgtimezone /usr/local/cpanel/whostmgr/docroot/cgi/softaculous/enduser/main/functions.php 68
WARNING
WARNING
WARNING
WARNING
```

growthwo_26_97197_upgrade_err.log

```
NOTICE Undefined offset: 1 /usr/local/cpanel/whostmgr/docroot/cgi/softaculous/enduser/main/functions.php 11536
WARNING
WARNING
WARNING
NOTICE Undefined index: pgtimezone /usr/local/cpanel/whostmgr/docroot/cgi/softaculous/enduser/main/functions.php 68
NOTICE Undefined index: no_dir_exists /usr/local/cpanel/whostmgr/docroot/cgi/softaculous/enduser/main/backup.php 245
NOTICE Undefined offset: 1 /usr/local/cpanel/whostmgr/docroot/cgi/softaculous/enduser/main/functions.php 11536
WARNING
WARNING
WARNING
NOTICE Undefined index: pgtimezone /usr/local/cpanel/whostmgr/docroot/cgi/softaculous/enduser/main/functions.php 68
NOTICE Undefined index: no_dir_exists /usr/local/cpanel/whostmgr/docroot/cgi/softaculous/enduser/main/backup.php 245
```

Comment: did you check the log  file and inside tmp folder?

Comment: hello check, I had added log files in question

Comment: you posted only warning & notice error. what about other logs?

Answer (score -1):

Via ftp delete or rename the current theme. Then try accessing your wp-admin. If this works then you should get a fresh copy of the theme and install it again. If this doesn't work rename the 'plugins' folder.

Now try again.

If you still get the same error message then try uploading a fresh set of WP core files.

Failing that, it would seem like some issue at the server level.

Comment: Why was my answer downvoted? This is a perfectly legitimate approach to debugging WordPress issues!!! Also, why the feck downvote and not leave a comment???